# Emptying a DAO recordset or Creating an Empty DAO recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access

So this may seem a bit of an odd question. However, I am trying to make a simple If-Else statement regarding whether or not to find records.

The first part goes like this:

`If String Meets Criteria
   Open Recordset
Else
   Recordset Is Empty
End If`

I did do a bunch of searching on empty sets, and so far my answer is just to create a quick SQL statement that returns empty. Is that really the simplest way to do this? I would never have set it up this way, but this is the fastest way to fix some code after which goes:

`If recordset.recordCount > 0 Then
[Rest of Code]`

Is there something a little more obvious that I haven't found yet? Like:

`Set Recordset = 0`

Comment: Please be a bit more explicit. Do you want to create an empty recordset, or do you want to test if one is empty?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Sorry, I posted this before it was complete. How about now?

Comment: Somewhat better, but what do you actually want to do with the recordset? Do you want  a recordset linked to a table without any records, so you can add to it? Or do you just want an unlinked, empty recordset, which is pretty much  useless?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth creating an empty set would work just as well.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The pretty much useless option.

Comment: How about `Set Recordset = Null`?

Comment: @Vityata, for the same reason in Erik's answer. I don't want a Null or Nothing recordset since I access the recordcount directly after. I wouldn't be able to with that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a recordset that doesn't contain any records and is not updateable, you can use the following code:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT 1 From MSysObjects WHERE FALSE")
```

DAO recordsets are always open and linked to a data source. Something like `Dim rs As New DAO.Recordset` won't work (in contrast to ADO recordsets, where you can dim an unopened recordset).

If you just want a placeholder object, you can also `Set rs = Nothing`, but you will encounter run-time errors when trying to access properties or methods in that case.

Comment: I imagine there isn't much a performance difference between doing what you suggested, and just opening a select query from a small local table that will return zero results? Or is there something special about MSysObjects?

Comment: There is something special about `MSysObjects`. It's not an actual table, but a representation of the objects Access stores, and it's not updateable. However, the main things are the `SELECT 1` -> non-updateable column, and `WHERE FALSE`, comparison that doesn't need to evaluate any fields in the table. Afaik Access doesn't even check the table, since it doesn't need to.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for hashing out the issue at hand with me, I did vote you up, but my reputation is too low for it to show publicly.